# Get all max and min values from df.groupby.().size() result

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1' : ['MM1', 'MM1', 'MM1', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM4', 'MM4', 'MM4'],
    'col2' : ['S1', 'S1', 'S3', 'S3', 'S4', 'S4', 'S2', 'S2', 'S2'],
    'col3' : [1,1,2,3,4,3,2,2,4]
    })
```

This gives me the grouped by result and the count

```
df.groupby(["col1", "col3"]).size()
```

This gives me the first result of the maximum

```
df.groupby(["col1", "col3"]).size().idxmax()
```

However, I want all maximum occurence. Everything I find on Stackoverflow is, when there is already a column with, i.e. the count. And then there are multiple maximums in the count column. But this is different here. I group by two values and then I want the maximum/minimum values of the result of this grouping. How to do this in pandas?

Here I expect

```
(M1, 2)
(M2, 4)
(M4, 4)
```

Edit:

```
df.groupby(["col1", "col3"]).size()
```

gives me

```
col1  col3       <- lets name this column count
MM1   1       2
      2       1
MM2   3       2
      4       1
MM4   2       2
      4       1
```

Lets name the unnamed columns `count`.

1. How do I get all the maximum*s* in the `count column`? Hence, this:

   `2, 2, 2`
2. How do I get its corresponding values from `col1` and `col2`? Something like this (column names only for clarity):

```
col1, col3, count
MM1,  1,    2
MM2   3     2
MM4   2     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yiu can convert second level (`col3`) to column. so possible aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and [`GroupBy.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(["col1", "col3"])
         .size()
         .reset_index(level=0)
         .groupby('col1')
         .agg(col3 = (0,'idxmax'), count=(0, 'max')))

print (df1)
      col3  count
col1             
MM1      1      2
MM2      3      2
MM4      2      2
```

Comment: @Stophface - What should be ouput?

Comment: I edited my Q. I could not add it here in the comment because it needed some formatting.

Comment: And, btw. What does `groupby(level=0)` (your last code snippet) do? What does `level=0` mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
df.groupby(["col1"])["col3"].max()
```